# Trying to setup an audio unit graph with a buffer of samples as the input

Tags: core-audio

I am trying to implement a simple audio unit graph that goes:

buffer of samples->low pass filter->generic output

Where the generic output would be copied into a new buffer that could then be processed further, saved to disk, etc.

All of the examples I can find online having to do with setting up an audio unit graph involve using a generator with the kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer as the input source...  I am dealing with a buffer of samples already acquired, so those examples do not help...  Based on looking around in the AudioUnitProperties.h file, it looks like I should be using using is kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer?

I can't seem to much documentation on how to hook this up, so I am quite stuck and am hoping someone here can help me out.

To simplify things, I just started out by trying to get my buffer of samples to go straight to the system output, but am unable to make this work...

```
  #import "EffectMachine.h"
  #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
  #import "AudioHelpers.h"
  #import "Buffer.h"

  @interface EffectMachine ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) Buffer *buffer;
  @end

  typedef struct EffectMachineGraph {
      AUGraph   graph;
      AudioUnit input;
      AudioUnit lowpass;
      AudioUnit output;
  } EffectMachineGraph;

  @implementation EffectMachine {
      EffectMachineGraph machine;
  }

  -(instancetype)initWithBuffer:(Buffer *)buffer {
      if (self = [super init]) {
          self.buffer = buffer;

          // buffer is a simple wrapper object that holds two properties:
          // a pointer to the array of samples (as doubles) and the size (number of samples)

      }
      return self;
  }

  -(void)process {
      struct EffectMachineGraph initialized = {0};
      machine = initialized;

      CheckError(NewAUGraph(&machine.graph),
                 "NewAUGraph failed");

      AudioComponentDescription outputCD = {0};
      outputCD.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
      outputCD.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
      outputCD.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

      AUNode outputNode;
      CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(machine.graph,
                                &outputCD,
                                &outputNode),
                 "AUGraphAddNode[kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput] failed");

      AudioComponentDescription inputCD = {0};
      inputCD.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
      inputCD.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer;
      inputCD.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

      AUNode inputNode;
      CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(machine.graph,
                                &inputCD,
                                &inputNode),
                 "AUGraphAddNode[kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer] failed");

      CheckError(AUGraphOpen(machine.graph),
                 "AUGraphOpen failed");

      CheckError(AUGraphNodeInfo(machine.graph,
                                 inputNode,
                                 NULL,
                                 &machine.input),
                 "AUGraphNodeInfo failed");

      CheckError(AUGraphConnectNodeInput(machine.graph,
                                         inputNode,
                                         0,
                                         outputNode,
                                         0),
                 "AUGraphConnectNodeInput");

      CheckError(AUGraphInitialize(machine.graph),
                 "AUGraphInitialize failed");

      // prepare input

      AudioBufferList ioData = {0};
      ioData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
      ioData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
      ioData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)(2 * self.buffer.size);
      ioData.mBuffers[0].mData = self.buffer.samples;

      ScheduledAudioSlice slice = {0};
      AudioTimeStamp timeStamp  = {0};

      slice.mTimeStamp    = timeStamp;
      slice.mNumberFrames = (UInt32)self.buffer.size;
      slice.mBufferList   = &ioData;

      CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(machine.input,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleAudioSlice,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                      0,
                                      &slice,
                                      sizeof(slice)),
                 "AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp] failed");

      AudioTimeStamp startTimeStamp = {0};
      startTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
      startTimeStamp.mSampleTime = -1;

      CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(machine.input,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                      0,
                                      &startTimeStamp,
                                      sizeof(startTimeStamp)),
                 "AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduleStartTimeStamp] failed");

      CheckError(AUGraphStart(machine.graph),
                 "AUGraphStart failed");

  //    AUGraphStop(machine.graph);  <-- commented out to make sure it wasn't stopping before actually finishing playing.
  //    AUGraphUninitialize(machine.graph);
  //    AUGraphClose(machine.graph);

  }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH16-SW8) you're looking for.

To summarize: setup your augraph, setup your audio units & add them to the graph, write & attach a *rendercallback* function on the first node in your graph. Run the graph. Note that the *rendercallback* is where your app will be asked to provide buffers of samples to the augraph. This is where you'll need to read from your buffers and fill the buffers supplied by the rendercallback. I think this is what you're missing.

If you're on iOS8, i recommend [AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#502), which helps conceal some of the grungier boiler-platey details of graphs and effects

Extras:

1. Complete pre-iOS8 [example code](https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph) on github
2. iOS [Music player app](https://github.com/pourhadi/DPMusicController) that reads audio from your MP3 library into a circular buffer and then processes it via an augraph (using a mixer & eq AU). You can see how a rendercallback is setup to read from a buffer, etc.
3. [Amazing Audio Engine](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine)
4. [Novocaine Audio library](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine)

Comment: Well, I followed those docs and still can't quite get this to work.  This is an OS X project, not iOS btw...  I am getting a -50 error code for setting the asbd for my output unit..   I am still trying simplify things by just going from my buffer to default output.  This is my code -> https://gist.github.com/patrick99e99/e26aae3917bac176b65a

Comment: OSX ahh, I assumed iOS, that makes it easier ... I have a look at your gist and comment

Comment: Your asbd looks wrong: you have *asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;* but then *asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;*. Floats are strictly 32-bits, so when you try to set the streamformat on the outputunit, it doesn't like it because the ASBD doesn't make sense. If you have a xcodeproj, that I can just run on Yosemite, I could help more

Comment: Sure, it's the "EffectMachine" class.  My goal is to create a new Buffer instance with the low pass filtered version of my original Buffer. Right now, it's just taking the input buffer, and sending it directly to the output via the AUGraph.   The lowpass filter stuff is in there but commented out...  This EffectMachine class is attempting to process a buffer of samples on app run, so when you launch the app, you'll see the -50 error code.  There is another class, "Sampler" that ouputs a buffer similaryly but without an AUGraph, and it works fine... https://github.com/patrick99e99/BlueWizard

Comment: hey I had a look at your code and there are a few problems, your input unit init (AUGraphNodeInfo) has a NULL AudioComponentDescription, and your ASBD is still busted, you have bits-per-channel set to 32, but bytes-per-frame & bytes-per-packet are set to 2, rather than 4. This is why you're getting a -50 param err. I didn't look further, but there may be other issues, like your choice of input unit (why not  have an effect-unit->OutputUnit) and with a rendercallback on the effect unit? I definitely recommend stepping through a working example in the links in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking and helping me out with this...  So you think I should use the low pass unit as the "input" and put the render callback on that, and not even bother with an input node?

Comment: I do, I think that would simplify things a lot. After you set things up. Put breakpoints in Xcode and examine the ASBDs and ensure the objects look correct and your callback in being called etc after you start your graph.